# Use of "self" in a python class

Tags: python, concept

I am learning about classes in python and doing a small exercise. Here I have created a class "Progression" and having issue with the print_progression method. I understood the TypeError that I was getting but didn`t understood the solution. The solution was to pass self to next method. So based on the solution, should I deduce that self is of type "iter".

```
class Progression:
  """ Iterator producing a generic progression.
  Default progresssion : 0,1,2 """

  def __init__(self, start=0):
    self._current = start
  
  def _advance(self):
    """ This should be overridden by a subclass to customize progression """
    self._current += 1
    return self._current
  
  def __next__(self):
    if self._current == None:
      raise StopIteration()
    else:
      return self._advance()

  def __iter__(self):
    return self._current

  def print_progression(self,values_to_print):
    if self._current != None:
      print(type(self))
      # print(isinstance(self, iter)) # TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
      print(" ".join(str(next(self._current)) for i in range(0,values_to_print)))
```

Creating instance of the class

```
p = Progression(start=1)
p.print_progression(3)
```

Error

```
 <class '__main__.Progression'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-19a69bdc9721> in <module>()
      1 p = Progression(start=1)
----> 2 p.print_progression(3)

1 frames
<ipython-input-81-f0653f30c8f0> in print_progression(self, values_to_print)
     25       print(type(self))
     26       # print(isinstance(self, iter)) # TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
---> 27       print(" ".join(str(next(self._current)) for i in range(0,values_to_print)))
     28 

<ipython-input-81-f0653f30c8f0> in <genexpr>(.0)
     25       print(type(self))
     26       # print(isinstance(self, iter)) # TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
---> 27       print(" ".join(str(next(self._current)) for i in range(0,values_to_print)))
     28 

TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator
```

I found that self._current is an int type and should not be passed to next method. Instead I should just pass self to next method and it works correctly.

```
class Progression:
  """ Iterator producing a generic progression.
  Default progresssion : 0,1,2 """

  def __init__(self, start=0):
    self._current = start
  
  def _advance(self):
    """ This should be overridden by a subclass to customize progression """
    self._current += 1
    return self._current
  
  def __next__(self):
    if self._current == None:
      raise StopIteration()
    else:
      return self._advance()

  def __iter__(self):
    return self._current

  def print_progression(self,values_to_print):
    if self._current != None:
      print(type(self))
      # print(isinstance(self, iter)) # TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
      print(" ".join(str(next(self)) for i in range(0,values_to_print)))
```

Comment: change `str(next(self._current)` to `str(self._current+1)`

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because `__iter__` is what gets called when you try to iterate over your custom class instance.
That's why when you iterate over your class it works fine because your class is iterable as long as you implemented the `__iter__` function.

the iterations return consequtive counting because on every `next` function, it's actually calls your custom `__next__` function which as you implement - invoke `self._advance()` which preceed `self._current` (again, the variable which returned on `__iter__`).

hope this explanation make sense for you.